# How to change the text "Send Request" to Pending after the request is send from particular array element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I have an array with a number of elements in it and I am using its data in my component such as name, email, etc...  And it also has a button to send request, So when the user clicks on send request if the response returns true I want to change the text of button from Send to Pending

I tried using state after the response but it changes the text to all the elements. I want to make a change only to the clicked element.

```
{this.state.set.map((item, index) => {
return (
{..data}
<Button onPress={() => this.sendRequest(this.state.set[index].id)}>
<Text>Send Request</Text>
</Button>)})}

  sendRequest(UserID) {
        {fetch requests...}
            .then((data) => {
                if (data == true) {
{Change text to Pending}
                }})    }
```

After the response true from services I want to change the text of the button to pending for the specific index for which it was clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to have a conditional rendering instance on the text for every item on the array.

First you need to add to every item of the array a pending variable, so you know which one you need to change. To do this just do:

```
var pending=this.state.set.map(item=>{
    let obj=item
    obj.pending=false
    return obj
})
this.setState({set: pending})
```

You need to run this function somewhere in your code, for example in componentDidMount.

Then you need to change the `pending` key to true based off index. This would become, inside your if:

```
 sendRequest(UserID, index) {              //remember to pass the index
  {fetch requests...}
      .then((data) => {
          if (data == true) {
              let arr=this.state.set
              arr[index].pending=true
              this.setState({ set: arr })
          }
        })    
      }
```

Then, the text component would become:

```
<Text>{item.pending? "Pending..." : "Send Request" }</Text>
```

If you ever need to change pending to false, you just have to:

```
toggleOff(index){      //remember to .bind() it
    let arr=this.state.set
    arr[index].pending=false
    this.setState({ set: arr })
}
```